# I am in search of a funds recovery service

Tags: recovery

I need help to recover 40k USDT stolen from a meta mask wallet. I have heard that it can be done.
I wanted an air drop and was robed by a sender.

Comment: If it was transfered from your account to another account, then it can't be undone. But good luck.

Comment: In any case, share your account address so we can try to figure out what happened.

Comment: You cannot revert a transaction that has already been sent on the blockchain, sorry for your loss

Answer (score 2):

What happened is likely you have approved the sender to transfer your USDT away. If that is the case, then there is no way the funds can be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

Tether offers a recovery service for their USDT tokens.

[Read more about Tether token Recoveries here](https://tether.to/en/tether-token-recoveries/).

Note that this is specific service for Tether and does not work in the context of other tokens. Also note that it is unlikely that you are able to recover any USDT, as scammers usually exit from USDT to non-censorable tokens right away.